# Unescaped apostrophe causing SQL import errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I have a `CSV` file that I'm importing into an SQL table on Microsoft SQL Server. the CSV file is around 1.6 million records long (tab delimited) and contains a string for each record which can (and must retain post-import if in the CSV file) have an apostrophe in it. The record would be something similar to:

`GB McCombie's Court    AB10 1AW    George St/Harbour Ward  Scotland    SCT         Aberdeen City`

The apostrophes throughout the CSV file are breaking the import by, I'm assuming, quoting out half of my data until another apostrophe is found later on, and then the format is destroyed.

Is there a way I can mass escape apostrophes in an SQL import?

Comment: Is that an example of the whole row? Is that TAB delimited? And no field identifiers (quotes around the fields)?

Comment: What is the import tool, BULK INSERT or what ?

Comment: @Serg **Tasks -> import data** on SQL server when right clicking on a database, loads the SQL server import and export wizard.

Comment: The apostrophe is a special character in SQL that specifies the beginning and end of string data. This means that to use it as part of your literal string data you need to escape the special character. With a single quote this is typically accomplished by doubling your quote.

Comment: @SeanCoetzee that's the full row as is, as found in the CSV file. No identifiers but there is a header on the first row of the file, if that's relevant.

Comment: @NeerajKumar Without manually going through 1.6 million records manually, I can't seem to find a way to escape the apostrophes, as I said in my question.